# Bootstrap form validation changing success and error colors

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This is my form, i want the form to change colors when errors/something occurs.

Example, if a user did not input anything in a required field,
 i want it to change colors using bootstrap's css classes, can anyone teach me how i could make that happen?
p.s. i am new, so sorry for a newbie question.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type = "submit" id="button" name="button" value = "Submit" class="btn btn-success">
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Totally depends on what you use to do the validation. Are you using browser native validations? There are CSS selectors. Are you using plain JS you wrote with regex or 3rd party libraries to do the validation, you may get a css class as a hook to style it. More info on that would help.

Comment: @PraveenPuglia i am using codeigniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS selector for this purpose (`:invalid`), but on the individual input level. You can color the whole form by checking for children which are invalid, like so:

```css
/* add space to denote child element */
form :invalid {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap, just add `has-error` class to form group.

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information, look the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-help-text

And live demo: http://jsbin.com/daxocivoho/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text color to green for correct inputs and red for wrong inputs:

```
.form-control:valid {
  color:green;
}
.form-control:invalid {
  color:red;
}
```

You can also change the border color to red for wrong inputs as follows:

```
.form-control:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```